# Jquery resize() on resizing window

Tags: jquery

Nevermind, I solved it. I just need to wrap around my function with $(window).resize(function());

I have a container wrapper around the 3 div which are display inline-block. The two of the first div have certain size. And I want the third div take the left over width. This is my function but it doesnt work as I expected.

```js
var totalW = $(".container").width();
var w1 = $(".box1").width();
var w2 = $(".box2").width();
var w3 = totalW - w1 - w2 - 10;

//$(".box3").css("width", w3); // This code doesnt work on resize.

$(".box3").resize(function() {
  $(".box3").css("width", w3);
});
```

```css
div.container {
  width=100%;
}
div.container > div {
  display: inline-block;
}
div.box1 {
  width: 20px;
  background: red;
}
div.box2 {
  width: 20px;
  background: green;
}
div.box3 {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="box1">1</div>
  <div class="box2">2</div>
  <div class="box3">3</div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not need js for this

```css
div.container {
  width: 100%;
}
div.left {
  float: left;
}
div.box1 {
  width: 20px;
  background: red;
}
div.box2 {
  width: 20px;
  background: green;
}
div.box3 {
  background: yellow;
  margin-left: 40px; /* to shift background color */
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box1 left">1</div>
  <div class="box2 left">2</div>
  <div class="box3">3</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

First, there is a typo error on your `div.container` css definition. Change `=` to `:`, and it should be like this:

```
div.container {
  width: 100%;
}
```

Based on your script you are trying to change the box width when you are resizing "`.box3`" div.

You might be looking for `$(window).resize` not `$(".box3").resize`:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    $(".box3").css({"width": w3});
});
```

you might also want to update the value of your variables on resize:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    totalW = $(".container").width();
    w1 = $(".box1").width();
    w2 = $(".box2").width();
    w3 = totalW - w1 - w2 - 10;
    $(".box3").css({"width": w3});
});
```

[HERE'S A DEMO, TRY TO RESIZE THE DISPLAY BOX](http://jsfiddle.net/mjrngok3/1/)